# How can I re-register my blogs widgets?

Tags: widgets

I deleted my wp_options database file in error. I replaced it with a clean install file.

Now my widgets are still present in my widgets area but none are recognized by wp.

Am I right in thinking that I somehow need to re register my sites widgets so that wordpress can see them in order for them to become active?

If so, how do I do this?

Currently my site is displaying a default list of pages, categories etc in the sidebar area.

Please understand that I am no programmer but I will do my best to follow any answers.

Marc

Comment: Just to add....I just downloaded a brand new recent comments plugin to try to see if wp in seeing or registering any comments. I activated the new never used before plugin and inserted it into sidebar but again nothing seen on front page. Perhaps this is not a registration issue?

Comment: Please put essential information into the question. You can always edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a wp_options database "file" to my knowledge.  Are you referring to the wp_options table?  Maybe you're working with sql files or something in a way I'm not familiar with?

If you wiped the database table, how did you go about replacing it with a clean one?  And if this is indeed a file, please include details about the location of the file.

I'm pretty sure that "Widget Registering" is not what you need to do.  Widgets should be registered on-the-fly everytime Wordpress is accessed.  Every plugin and functions.php file does a register() function call each time you access the site.  If you are seeing the widgets listed in the widget area, then they are registered correctly.  If you are seeing the sidebars listed in the widget area, then they too are registered correctly.

It sounds to me like you broke your database by wiping out some critical information that was in that table.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that you recreated the `wp-options` database table, is that just a blank table, or does it contain data?

It seems like you're missing values from that table, and need to set up a fresh install of WordPress. To do this, backup and then delete all of the tables in your database, and then visit your blog to run the install again.

To preserve your blog content, you can use the import/export feature under the **Tools** menu in the WordPress administration dashboard.

The other thing you could try is switching to another theme, and then switching back again.